# git add a file that's inside a directory beginning with _ (underscore)

Tags: git, directory, underscore.js, addition, root

I have a project in c:/wamp64/www/abc/ and I want to add `git add` a file that's whose path is c:/wamp64/www/abc/_/vendor/xyz.css

Project's root is c:/wamp64/www/abc/

So when I run the following command

```
`git add _/vendor/xyz.css`
```

(I have git in c:/wamp64/www/abc/)

it says `fatal: pathspec` then displays the path `did not match any file`

I've also tried 
`git add /_/vendor/xyz.css`
but that also didn't worked.

How can I add a file that's in a directory that begins with an underscore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do:

```
cd _/vendor/
git add xyz.css
```

You can also simply do:

```
git add ./_/vendor/xyz.css
```

Or use windows path separator:

```
git add "_\vendor\xyz.css"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you think of any other way by which I don't need to change directories?

Comment: I added a simpler solution.

Comment: BTW. I just tried and got the full error : `fatal: pathspec '_C:/Program Files/Git/vendor/xyz.css' did not match any files` <= the displayed path is important here!

Answer (score 1):

`git add "_\/vendor/xyz.css"`

Insert a "\" between "_" and the first "/".